# Use Spring in a WAR

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I did jar application with Spring 3 TaskScheduler. I run this app with main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
  ctx.load("classpath:scheduler-app-context.xml");
  ctx.refresh();
  while (true) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Is it please possible run this jar, main method in web application(war file)? How to run this in web.xml.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:scheduler-app-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This will instantiate your Spring context from the XML file. So it's not necessary to do this by hand as in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need simple scheduler in war(with spring framework), you can also do something like this:

(in Spring the "@PostConstruct" will initialize scheduler - so there is no need for main method)

```
    @Component
    public class Scheduler {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);


        @PostConstruct
        private void initializeTenSecSchedule() {

            final List<Runnable> jobs = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

            jobs.add(doSomeTestLogs());
            jobs.add(doSomeTestLogs2());

            final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(jobs.size());

            for(Runnable job : jobs){

                scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(job, 10, 10, SECONDS);

            }

        }

        /**
         * ---------------------some schedule tasks--------------------------
         */

        private Runnable doSomeTestLogs(){

            final Runnable job = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 

                    LOG.debug("== foo SCHEDULE a", 1);
                    System.out.println("Method executed at every 10 seconds. Current time is :: "+ new Date());

                }
            };

            return job;

        }

        private Runnable doSomeTestLogs2(){

            final Runnable job = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 

                    LOG.debug("== foo SCHEDULE b", 1);
                    System.out.println("Method executed at every 10 seconds. Current time is :: "+ new Date());

                }
            };

            return job;

        }

    }
```